# How to update the django model when it does not detect changes?

Tags: django, postgresql

I encounter an error on my Django application, I cannot update my models thanks to makemigrations
It returns "No changes detected"
My database is in postgresql
My app is well saved in my settings.py file and I have the migrations folder inside the app, I don't see where the problem can come from.
Do you have any idea what it could be?

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Gestflotte (models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True),
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    nb_engins = models.IntegerField(max_length=50),
    type_fichier = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    calculateur = models.CharField(max_length=255),
```

**Update**

The problem was the ',' at the end of the fields
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `makemigrations` only when modifying your models fields/attributes, if you just change the methods of your models.py class (like overriding models methods or creating new ones) you don't need to use `makemigrations`.

And if you don't have your changes updated in your database, did you think of using `migrate` after making your migrations ?

Comment: What I want is to be able to add new fields, so I add them to models.py and save the file, and at the time of makemigrations it tells me that it does not detect any changes so the migrate behind does not pass no more

Comment: And by doing ```python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name``` it still doesn't work ? Documentation about it is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps).

That's all I'm able to think of at the moment

Comment: Yes I tried too, I'm not sure what could be the cause but thank you anyway I'll dig into the documentation

Comment: if you've solved you problem please share the  solution for this I facing the same problem, Thankyou